# C++11 Passing 'this' as paramenter for std::make_shared

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, this, make-shared

I'm trying to pass 'this' to the constructor using std::make_shared

Example:

```
// headers
class A 
{
public:
   std::shared_ptr<B> createB();
}


class B 
{
private:
   std::shared_ptr<A> a;

public:
   B(std::shared_ptr<A>);
}


// source
std::shared_ptr<B> A::createB()
{
   auto b = std::make_shared<B>(this); // Compiler error (VS11 Beta)
   auto b = std::make_shared<B>(std::shared_ptr<A>(this)); // No compiler error, but doenst work
   return b;
}
```

However this does not work properly, any suggestions how I can properly pass this as an argument?

Comment: "does not work properly" - why not? what happens? why is that bad? please describe problems in non-generalities, so that future readers can find them with search terms.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think what you probably want here is [`shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

```
// headers
class A : std::enable_shared_from_this< A >
{
public:
   std::shared_ptr<B> createB();
}


class B 
{
private:
   std::shared_ptr<A> a;

public:
   B(std::shared_ptr<A>);
}


// source
std::shared_ptr<B> A::createB()
{
   return std::make_shared<B>( shared_from_this() );
}
```

---

Update to include [comments from David Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534220/c11-passing-this-as-paramenter-for-stdmake-shared#comment13628496_10534285):

Note that `shared_from_this()` should *never* be called on an object that isn't already managed by a `shared_ptr`.  This is valid:

```
shared_ptr<A> a( new A );
a->createB();
```

While the following leads to undefined behaviour (attempting to call `delete` on `a`):

```
A a;
a.createB();
```

Comment: It is important to note that `shared_from_this()` requires that the current object is already managed in a `shared_ptr`. I.e. `int main() { A a; a.createB(); }` is undefined behavior, while `int main() { shared_ptr<A> a( new A ); a->createB(); }` is correct.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Absolutely.  I've updated the answer accordingly.  Thanks.